# How Implement ASP.NET Identity hide some column and row table in viewresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have an application based on ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Identity 3.

I am familiar with claims and policies.

I created a dynamic system for every controller action to create and read Claims.

In my App, I have to hide some columns and some rows in the table for the user has not a specific or dynamic claim!

Is there any way to do this? if not.. what should I do for this scenario?
Should I create something like ClaimStore to store some static Claims? like `Contoller.SelectAction.ColumnName1`?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried filtering your desired rows in your view model rather than than the view , this way you can leverage the system you mentioned for getting and checking the claims? You can achieve that in the view as well by appending a bit with every row and checking that in the razor/ui to show it or not.

Comment: I fixed the Column solution. I use a ClaimStore class for every column must be Hide or Show to end user. but for rows.. Can I have access to Httpcontext in ViewModel? if so how can to filter query result with user Claims? @FrankenstineJoe Joe

Comment: Httpcontext will be available in the controller action method, you can leverage it there or pass it to view model to leverage your functionality.
pseudocode :
var viewmodel.yourPropertyToShow=GetdataFromWhereever().FilterRowsOnYourClaims();

Comment: @FrankenstineJoe Do you have any Example of these FilterRowsOnYourClaims() ? I don't know how to implement it. Thanks.